# Databinding XmlDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xmldocument

I have a UserControl where I want to bind textboxes to an XmlDocument.
The important parts of the xaml-code looks like:

```
...
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <XmlDataProvider x:Name="Data" XPath="employee"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
...
<TextBox Text={Binding XPath=general/description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
...
```

In the constructor of the usercontrol I have the following lines:

```
string xmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Thread.GetDomain().BaseDirectory, "Data", "TestXml.xml");
FileStream stream = new FileStream(xmlPath, FileMode.Open);
this.Data.Document = new XmlDocument();
this.Data.Document.Load(stream);
```

If I changed textbox-text, the XmlDocument Data is not updated. What do I have to do, to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code worked for me. Instead of using a stream, I used a hard-coded data.

XAML File :

```
    <Window x:Class="TestWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="Data" XPath="employee"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox Width="100" Foreground="Red" Height="20" Text="{Binding XPath=general/description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Content="Test" Width="50" Height="20" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestWPFApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Data.Document = new XmlDocument();
            this.Data.Document.LoadXml(@"<employee><general><description>Test Description</description></general></employee>");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = this.Data.Document.SelectSingleNode("descendant::description").InnerText;
        }
    }
}
```